# Chrome Angry Birds engine?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas

Was [Chrome AngryBirds game](http://chrome.angrybirds.com/) made using html5 canvas? And if yes: what kind of engine did they use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not support questions asking "how was this game made" or "how did this game do that". Such questions are mostly speculative, and not constructive; we usually edit the question to ask "how can ***I*** do this feature, but this question is too old for such edits to be constructive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. ForPlay.

WebGL and Canvas 2D code paths exist for maximum performance and platform support respectively. The [ForPlay](http://code.google.com/p/forplay/) GWT library helps with the abstraction. See the Google IO presentation [Kick-Ass Game Programming with Google Web Toolkit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_sbusEUz5w) for details.

Comment: I just watched the presentation and I think I would like to try out ForPlay in a later project. Seems like a really nice approach. Thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: AFAIK ForPlay aka PlayN does not let you write in "HTML5" ... the sourcebase is in Java, and it compiles into other formats. Read: You're not actually writing in HTML5; machine translates your Java to HTML5..

Answer (score 6):

It is based on WebGL (which means canvas is used, but not the standard canvas environment).
As iOS uses OpenGL I think they ported that to javascript.

Comment: I made some test http://html5test.com/ and it said that I have no WebGL context;)

Comment: And my WebGL debugger popped up so it can also use WebGL, so uh, what Vincent said.

Answer (score 4):

Inspecting the page element gives me `<canvas width="1024" height="768"></canvas>` so I guess that means it is canvas.

As for the engine, I assume they ported their iOS one.